# What are possible mistakes when connecting to SQL Server from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a login form in C# connecting to a SQL Server 2008. And the data reader has an error. What should I do?

This is my project for finals

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAMSUNG-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LOGIN;Integrated Security=True");//this is my sql pc server name
SqlDataReader dr;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_log where Username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password = '", con);

con.Open();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("un", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pw", textBox2.Text);

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();//this is my problem//

if (dr.HasRows)//and this//
{
    menu menu = new menu();
    menu.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
con.Close();
```

I expect this output: if the password is correct go to new form
and if the password is incorrect the message box will appear and say "error".

Comment: The *worst* mistake you can make with data access is: SQL injection; and you've done exactly that... did you mean `"Select * from tbl_log where Username = @un and Password = @pw"` ? The second worst mistake you can make with security is storing passwords as text; you're 2-for-2! The third mistake would probably be: not "disposing" the disposable objects - so... lots of `using` around `con`, `cmd`, and `dr`. The fourth mistake would be having code that touches the database *and* the UI all in one method :) If I was going for a fifth, it would be: returning columns you don't need/use.

Comment: To me it looks like you're atleast trying to avoid SQL injection by using `Parameters.AddWithValue` but you're doing it wrong. I suspect you've read a few different sources of how to implement the desired behaviour but mixed them up in a way that makes no sense. @Marc Gravell has some very good points you should listen to.

Comment: oh, and finally: using SQL Server 2008 - although I'll be fair here and concede that there *is* extended support available for another 3 months. But... come on; it is 2019!

Answer (score 2):

There is so much here that needs to be different. The big things are:

- Correct query parameterization (avoid sql injection attacks)
- Don't store passwords in plain text. **Don't even do this in learning/practice code!** Passwords should be *one-way hashed* (don't encrypt them, either) using a reputable algorithm.
- `using` blocks to avoid leaving connections open if an exception is thrown, to avoid creating a denial-of-service situation to your database
- Don't mix UI and database access. Really, even my code below ought to have two layers, where the auth code is in a separate class from the database code

Something like this is much better:

```
public static class DB 
{
    private static string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SAMSUNG-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LOGIN;Integrated Security=True";

    public static bool ValidateUserCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
                        //PwdHash column should be Char(60) (not VarChar, not NChar)
        string sql = "Select PwdHash from tbl_log where Username = @User";

        string hash = "";
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            //use actual column types and lengths from the database here
            // Do NOT use AddWithValue()!
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = username;

            //keep the connection active for as brief a time as possible
            cn.Open();
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (!rdr.Read()) return false;    
                hash = (string)rdr["PwdHash"];
            }
        }
        //based on this NuGet bcrypt library:
        //https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Official/
        if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, hash)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you could use it from the user interface like this:

```
if (DB.ValidateUserCredentials(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text))
{
    menu mu = new menu(); //can't give a variable the same name as it's type
    mu.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
```

Comment: Another good note to make specifically (not just in the code) is to avoid [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Answer (score 1):

After all the correct remarks you've received from @Marc Gravell and more...

To refer specifically to your actual question, 
You should correct

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_log where Username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password = '", con);

//Here you're trying to add parameters that don't exist    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("un", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pw", textBox2.Text);
```

to

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_log where Username = @UserName and Password = @Password", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
```

Also to help you understand the error (and because it's a call to SQL),
you should wrap the code with `try-catch`

And one last remark since you're a beginner... 
Use meaningful names. Try to avoid abbreviations, it's a bad habit.

Comment: con/cn/conn+cmd+dr/rdr are common enough, I'm more concerned someone might be "under-experienced" if they actually write out the whole "command" or "reader" names.

Comment: This is probably the best answer to the original question. The original question wasn't asking for best practices or secure code, just how to get non-working code to work.